# password box does not mask my password WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a password box in WPF,
when in edit mode the password box does not mask my password.

Here is an example of my code:

```
<PasswordBox Width="200" Password="{Binding Path=Password, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

I have attempted including Passwordchar = '*'

Comment: Hello, can you accept my answer, please and thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you can't get password value direct in viewmodel due to security purpose, you have to create dependancy property.

below is code for password.

DP:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundPassword =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BoundPassword", typeof(string), typeof(PasswordBoxHelper), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnBoundPasswordChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindPassword = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "BindPassword", typeof(bool), typeof(PasswordBoxHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnBindPasswordChanged));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty UpdatingPassword =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UpdatingPassword", typeof(bool), typeof(PasswordBoxHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    private static void OnBoundPasswordChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var box = d as PasswordBox;
        if(d == null || !GetBindPassword(d))
        {
            return;
        }
        box.PasswordChanged -= HandlePasswordChanged;

        var newPassword = (string)e.NewValue;

        if(!GetUpdatingPassword(box))
        {
            box.Password = newPassword;
        }

        box.PasswordChanged += HandlePasswordChanged;
    }

    private static void OnBindPasswordChanged(DependencyObject dp, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var box = dp as PasswordBox;

        if(box == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        bool wasBound = (bool)(e.OldValue);
        bool needToBind = (bool)(e.NewValue);

        if(wasBound)
        {
            box.PasswordChanged -= HandlePasswordChanged;
        }

        if(needToBind)
        {
            box.PasswordChanged += HandlePasswordChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void HandlePasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var box = sender as PasswordBox;
        SetUpdatingPassword(box, true);
        SetBoundPassword(box, box.Password);
        SetUpdatingPassword(box, false);
    }

    public static void SetBindPassword(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(BindPassword, value);
    }

    public static bool GetBindPassword(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (bool)dp.GetValue(BindPassword);
    }

    public static string GetBoundPassword(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (string)dp.GetValue(BoundPassword);
    }

    public static void SetBoundPassword(DependencyObject dp, string value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(BoundPassword, value);
    }

    private static bool GetUpdatingPassword(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (bool)dp.GetValue(UpdatingPassword);
    }

    private static void SetUpdatingPassword(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(UpdatingPassword, value);
    }
```

and below is the XAML:

```
  <PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordBox" 
                                     utility:PasswordBoxHelper.BindPassword="true" 
                                     utility:PasswordBoxHelper.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password,  
        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Binding to password field in PasswordBox because of security.
Actually you can, but your password will be stored in memory.
Try this http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html

Answer (score 1):

Both @JRB and @BorisErmako answers are probably valid, yet somehow heavyweight.

You don't need two-way data binding, do you?  In most scenario you don't want to *update* the password field from code, do you?  I guess you don't.

Then, just use an event to get notified.  Inspired by [Bind a WPF passwordbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981169/bind-a-wpf-passwordbox) I did:

#### XAML:

```
<PasswordBox PasswordChanged="OnPasswordChanged" />
```

#### Code-behind event handler:

Assuming code-behind class has a pointer to the underlying model object as `myViewModelObject`.

```cs
private void OnPasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myViewModelObject.Password = ((PasswordBox)sender).Password;
}
```

This adds very few lines of code compared to the 89 to 108 extra lines of other answers.  Extra bonus: for all practical purposes, this seems fully compatible with advanced framework like [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/).

Answer (score 0):

For using a masked Password text box in WPF implement below methods:

Class constructor:

```
 public Login_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Password_Text_Box.MaxLength = 7; // password 7 characters in length
            AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;
        } // End of Login form initialization
```

Component validation:

```
  private void Password_Text_Box_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
            bool cancel = false;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password_Text_Box.Text)) {
                cancel = true;
                ErrorProvider.SetError(Password_Text_Box, " MISSING PASSWORD "); }
            e.Cancel = cancel; }
```

Logic behind a 'Key Press" action:

```
private void Password_Text_Box_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter) {
            // if ENTER is hit , do something
            e.Handled = true; //Handle the Keypress event (suppress the Beep) }
        Password_Text_Box.PasswordChar = '*'; // masking input right away
        e.Handled = !(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back);
        e = null;} // not allowing certain types of input
```

You could also implement a pictogram that reveals and hides the entered sequence:

```
   private void pictureBoxShowPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       if (Password_Text_Box.PasswordChar == '*' & Password_Text_Box.Text != null) {
                Password_Text_Box.PasswordChar = '\0'; } //revealing
            else if (Password_Text_Box.PasswordChar == '\0'){
                Password_Text_Box.PasswordChar = '*'; } } // hiding
```

What happens when you point and click the text box:

```
    private void Password_Text_Box_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (Password_Text_Box.Text == "Password") {
            Password_Text_Box.Text = ""; } }
```

All in all, you should be looking at something along these lines:

When a form and a text box loads, it displays a text - purpose of the component.
When a user points a mouse and clicks on the component, the purpose text disappears.
Upon entering a value, a masking symbol appears on the screen.
Nearby by the Reveal button lets, you see the entered value before submission.

[image: First Appearance]

[image: Select the text box by clicking]

[image: Entered Value]

[image: Reveal]