# How to make a return statement to open wpf windows in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm newbie to this stack overflow so this is my first question.

I've made a return statement so if this validation return 1, it will open a new window, otherwise, it won't be opened. Here is my code :

```
private int UserPassValidation()
    {
        if (txtUserName.Equals("admin") && txtPassword.Equals("admin"))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

private void LOGIN_BUTTON_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (UserPassValidation() == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                WindowView objWindowView = new WindowView();
                objWindowView.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch (System.Data.EntityException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Entity Exception", "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("...");
        }
    }
```

So, there is a "Username and password validation" and sign in button. And then, I insert "admin" on txtusername and admin on txtpassword too.

Then, when i click sign in button, it won't be opened. I don't know why, but it's supposed to be opened.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. :) Check if this helps you. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468433/wpf-window-return-value

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: I've edited my post in the bottom of the post

Comment: Place a breakpoint in your event handler and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, Aishvarya. But it seems that the solution doesn't match with my desires. But, once again, thank you :). (Sorry for the bad grammars)

Comment: @zmbq, I've done that, and it returns 0 afterall, because of that, I want to ask this question. Thank you :). I just want to know where is my mistake.

Comment: If `txtUserName` is the name of `TextBox`, you should compare the value with its `Text` property like `txtUserName.Text=="admin"`.

Comment: txtUserName is the name of TextBox, but txtPassword is the name of PasswordBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaaahhhh, finally work! So, this is my solution :

```
if (txtUserName.Text == "admin" && txtPassword.Password.ToString() == "admin")
```

Sorry, I'm forgot to tell you that txtPassword is a PasswordBox, but, thank you guys! :D

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your comparison is not  correct in UserPassValidation method. if txtUserName is a Textbox then you should compair thats Text property. like..

```
if (txtUserName.Text == "admin" && txtPassword.Text == "admin")
```

Comment: it seems work, but txtPassword doesn't have a ".Text" attribute, because txtPassword is a PasswordBox, so it's a compile error.

Comment: Here i had given answer . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186737/password-box-does-not-mask-my-password-wpf/20187687#20187687