# Bind a WPF passwordbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, passwordbox

I want to bind a Passwordbox in the XAML code. Now I found out that it isn´t possible to bind it because you haven´t any dependency property.

For my case I don´t need any security in my Application. I just don´t want to display clear text to the user. Is there any other option to realize a kind of passwordbox with a textbox or so on?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the property is `Password` and you can pass a string to it.

Comment: When i set my Binding like this: `Password="{Binding MyPassword}"` i got the error `"A binding cannot be set on the password property of type "passwordbox". A binding can only be set on a dependency property of a dependency object."` In this MyPassword is a StringProperty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind to a PasswordBox in MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483892/how-to-bind-to-a-passwordbox-in-mvvm)

Comment: Already checked this topic. For me it would be enough to have a Textbox without plaintext.. So it would be pretty more easy to handle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Password` property is not a dependency property -- for security reasons. You can easily get the plain-text password, though.

#### XAML:

```
<PasswordBox
    x:Name="passwordBox"
    PasswordChanged="OnPasswordChanged" />
```

#### Code-behind event handler:

```
private void OnPasswordChanged(
    object sender,
    RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(passwordBox.Password);
}
```

---

### Updates

- [Samuel Jack describes how to bind to a `PasswordBox` using attached properties](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html)
- [A discussion on security risk](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/security-risk-in-binding-wpf-passwordbox-password/)

Comment: No way to two way bind it?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: Actually, I just ran across an article that shows how to do this using attached properties. I'll update the post.

Comment: Not working , I wouldn't like to use events , I have a MVVM model , is there another solution?